# Condition module

Tags: 7

I want to use the Virtual site module, but it requires the Condition module I cannot find for Drupal.

Where should I download that module? Do you have a link I can use to download it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the condition module for D7. It is already added to VS module itself.
Here is the snapshot of the description of [its project page](http://drupal.org/project/virtual_site):

> The D7 version is the Virtual Sites module and the Condition module it depends **on rolled into one package**. While it retains all the functionality from the D6 version (even added a new condition to check for the user's browser, useful to recognize visitors with mobile devices), changes in Drupal itself made its setup slightly different. Installing it will enable the dependent VS Conditions module automatically.

Comment: ohh thanks, but can u tell me how to work with it, means how to create new sub-site using this extension ? Can u tell me any reference link to Steps to create new virtual site?

Comment: here is the [link to the modules documentation](http://drupal.org/node/231643).

Comment: while creating new virtual site it returns me a notice does it affect this module? if Yes then please tell me how to overcome it ?

Comment: this is beyond the scope of this question; but still the module won't be affected mostly, only the database gets affected.

Comment: @user10409 If you have additional questions, please post them separately using the "Ask Question" button.